# What code is allowed outside namespace except using directives

Tags: c#, scope, namespaces

Using directives outside namespace body is common practice, but what are other code which can be done outside namespace body.

Comment: Why? Are you encountering a problem? Is this going to relate to the Top Level Statements feature of newer C# versions?

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements for the top-level statements

Comment: A [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) is "used to declare a scope that contains a set of related objects." So logically speaking, if a namespace defines scope for objects, and we know that everything in C# (and some other OOP langauges) are associated with objects -> then there is no valid code that can be outside of namespaces. A namespace must be declared for objects to have a scope, and classes and objects are where we write our code. Top level statements simply do the dirty work for you

Comment: what exactly is the *purpose* of this question? SO isn't a site for *learning* a languages sysntax, so you should read the appropriate docs for that. Do you have a *specific* problem, e.g. a compiler-error in your code? Than feel free to add the relevant code here and the error you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace is optional. If it is omitted, types will be assigned to the global namespace. Therefore, every kind of code allowed at the top-level is allowed outside of the namespace.

```cs
// No namespace declaration here
public class MyClass()
{
}
```

You can explicitly specify this namespace like this:

```cs
var c = new global::MyClass();
```

The documentation says:

> The compiler adds a default namespace. This unnamed namespace, sometimes referred to as the global namespace, is present in every file. It contains declarations not included in a declared namespace. Any identifier in the global namespace is available for use in a named namespace.

See: [Learn / .NET / C# guide / Language reference / Keywords / namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace)